# fantastic worn condition

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "worn" mean in the following? Does it necessarily mean the jeans were damaged?

> Stevenson has run a denim repair shop in Los Angeles for nearly three decades -- but he had never found a pair quite like this. "These jeans are extremely rare -- especially in this fantastic **worn** condition and size," he told CNN.

https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/19th-century-levis-jeans-intl-scli/index.html

I've looked up many definitions of "worn" and "well-worn." For example, the American Heritage says "Affected OR damaged by wear or use." By this definition, a pair of worn jeans is not necessarily damaged. It could have just been softened or stretched somewhat. On the other hand, the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says "a worn object is old AND damaged, especially because it has been used a lot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Wear" is a type of damage, it is "damage" caused by normal use. You would expect something that has been used to become worn over time.

Fashion says that for some things, like these jeans, new (and so unworn) is not fashionable. So jeans in a worn condition are more valuable.

Comment: Is a well-worn jacket necessarily damaged?

Comment: Define "damage"   It is certainly not in a "new" condition.

Comment: I've looked up many definitions of "worn" and "well-worn." For example, the American Heritage says "Affected OR damaged by wear or use." By this definition, a pair of worn jeans is not necessarily damaged. It could have just been softened or stretched somewhat. On the other hand, the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says "a worn object is old AND damaged, especially because it has been used a lot"

Comment: Well exactly!  "softened and stretched" might be considered a form of "damage" to one person but not to another.  Rather than get into the ambiguities of meaning, let us merely note that "worn" means "not new, nor 'as new'".

Comment: If a coat is bleached by the sun, can it be described as "a worn coat"?

Comment: Is it "damage" caused by normal use?  you decide.   Probably the answer is "sometimes"